# Modify dead key behaviour

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I am using the keyboard layout: "English (Dvorak, intl., with dead keys)". Sometimes I write in French, and I would like to be able to type the c-cedilla (ç and Ç), the same as on my Windows machine, where I use the combination `'c`. When I try this same combination on my laptop which uses Ubuntu, I end up with `ć`.

I tried to modify the file `us` in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. I changed

`key <AD08> { [    c,          C,     copyright,             cent ] };`

to

`key <AD08> { [    c,          C,     ccedilla,             Ccedilla ] };`

This does allow me to type `ç` using Alt Gr + C, however, `'c` still becomes `ć`. How can I modify the behaviour of the dead keys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

- Generate a Portuguese locale

  ```
  sudo locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8
  ```
- Add this line to the `~/.profile` file:

  ```
  export LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8
  ```
- Relogin

Comment: I notice that some applications (e.g. Nautilus Dropbox) are now in Portuguese, which I don't speak. Is there maybe another way to achieve this, while keeping English as the preferred language for all programs?